# Kendo UI Grid Save on Cell Blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gridview, kendo-ui

I am trying to get my grid to save changes when you press enter or move off a cell (blur), and not have to use a save button in a grid toolbar.

I am having trouble getting it to work properly, my PHP/SQL works fine, so I am sure it is something wrong with the grid.

Here is my code:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: WEBROOT+"admin/fetch-toppers",
        update: {
            url: WEBROOT+"admin/update-topper",
            type: "POST"
        }
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
        alert(e.responseText);
    },
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                "id": {nullable: true},
                "Date": {editable: false},
                "name": {editable: false},
                "price": {editable: true}
            }
        }
    }
},
columns: [{field: "Date", width: 105}, {field: "name", title: "Topper"}, {field: "price", title: "Price", width: 125}],
height: 550,
filterable: true,
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
editable: true,
navigatable: true,
edit: function()
{
    //this.saveChanges()
}
});
```

I have tried many things and different events but it has no effect.

How can I get it to save cell values on blur?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your DataSource add:

```
change: function (e) {
                        if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                            this.sync();
                        }
                    },
```

it should look like:

```
dataSource: {
transport: {
    read: WEBROOT+"admin/fetch-toppers",
    update: {
        url: WEBROOT+"admin/update-topper",
        type: "POST"
    }
},
error: function(e)
{
    alert(e.responseText);
},
change: function (e) {
                        if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                            this.sync();
                        }
},
schema: {
    data: "data",
    model: {
        id: 'id',
        fields: {
            "id": {nullable: true},
            "Date": {editable: false},
            "name": {editable: false},
            "price": {editable: true}
        }
    }
}
```

},

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! There are many threads in the kendo forum that need to see this!

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use the **[change](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#change)** event of the dataSource to execute the **[sync](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#sync)** method of the dataSource.

```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
    transport: {
        read: WEBROOT+"admin/fetch-toppers",
        update: {
            url: WEBROOT+"admin/update-topper",
            type: "POST"
        }
    },
    change:function(){this.sync()},
    error: function(e)
    {
        alert(e.responseText);
    },
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            fields: {
                "id": {nullable: true},
                "Date": {editable: false},
                "name": {editable: false},
                "price": {editable: true}
            }
        }
    }
},
columns: [{field: "Date", width: 105}, {field: "name", title: "Topper"}, {field: "price", title: "Price", width: 125}],
height: 550,
filterable: true,
sortable: true,
pageable: true,
editable: true,
navigatable: true,
edit: function()
{
    //this.saveChanges()
}
});
```

Comment: How do I put into the context of what I have?

Comment: How do I change my code to implement what you suggest? I have tried everything and it still doesn't work, but it works fine with a save changes button, but that's not what I want.

Comment: I have updated my post, check the line above the dataSource error function

Comment: Have tried it, but now I just get a loader that never disappears.

Comment: I am getting Object [object Object] has no method 'sync'

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to achieve this: set autoSync to true on the data source: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/autosync

Answer (score -1):

You can also call your datasource sync right from the grid as follows (make sure you use setTimeout, as per Telerik in this [post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/incell-editing---saving-when-stepping-out-of-cell))...

```
save: function () {
     setTimeout(function() {
          yourDatasource.sync();
     }
}
```